# VBA If True add one value to another

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I'm in the process of learning VBA so I am pretty brand new to it. I am creating a dice game to just get practice and tinker with the code. I'm trying to find a way to either add or subtract the amount the user bets from the amount of money he has. So if he guesses closer to the dice rolled, he would win and win the amount of money he has bet and it would get added to his balance. My problem is trying to figure out how to add or subtract the bet amount from the balance. I'm trying to use an If statement that says if Player wins add bet to balance and if he loses subtract bet from balance. What is the best way of doing this in VBA? Thanks for any help you offer.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim bet As Integer
Dim balance As Integer
Dim player As Integer
Dim computer As Integer

bet = Range("B11").Value
balance = Range("A14").Value
player = Range("A19").Value
computer = Range("L19").Value
Range("D14").Value = 5000

Beep

If bet < balance Then Worksheets(1).Calculate
If player < computer Then MsgBox "You Won!"
If player > computer Then MsgBox "You Lost!"
If player = computer Then MsgBox "It's a Tie!"

If player < computer Then Range("D14").Value bet

If player > computer Then

End Sub
```

[Game and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZncnC.jpg)

Edit: Added Code

Comment: Could you copy/paste your code into your question please - a screenshot is very hard to copy/paste into the VBE on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If player < computer Then Range("D14").Value = Range("D14").Value + bet

If player > computer Then Range("D14").Value = Range("D14").Value - bet
```

or you could change the area to this

```
Beep

If bet < balance Then Worksheets(1).Calculate
If player < computer Then MsgBox "You Won!": Range("D14").Value = Range("D14").Value + bet
If player > computer Then MsgBox "You Lost!": Range("D14").Value = Range("D14").Value - bet
If player = computer Then MsgBox "It's a Tie!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return of what you are asking, using an IIF something like

```
if Computer<>Player then Range("D14").Value=Range("D14").Value + iif(Player>Computer,(0-dblStake),Stake‌​)
```